Errors were encountered while processing: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers: i386 AND amd64
Is it possible to resolve this error with my amd gpu drivers? I was trying to ugrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1 when I encountered an error and the process was stopped.

Could not instal 'sgml-base'

I tried this
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/sgml-base/supercatalog

which didn't seem to do anything. Then I tried
sudo apt-get install sgml-data metacity-common sgml-base --reinstall

which resulted in
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

So I used the command:
sudo dpkg --configure -a

Which gave me
dpkg: cycle found while processing triggers:
chain of packages whose triggers are or may be responsible:
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64 -> mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386
packages' pending triggers which are or may be unresolvable:
ca-certificates: update-ca-certificates
rygel: rygel-restart
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/vdpau
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
triggers looping, abandoned
AND
Errors were encountered while processing:
ca-certificates
rygel
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64
